# Python - Trying to print metadata into a table

Tags: python

I have a python script that gets the meta data of photos and prints it out into a text file for now however I'd like to print it into a table that look like that

```
| Filename | DPI | Height | Width | Format | Mode | Frames |
```

Here is the script:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import os
import os.path
import PIL

PIL.Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 384000000

rootdir = r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive - ISC Industries\Summer Intern 2022\Suspensia Pictures"

newfile = newfile = open('meta.txt', 'w')

for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
    # read the image data using PIL
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir, file))

    # extract other basic metadata
    info_dict = {
        "Filename": image.filename,
        "Image DPI": image.info['dpi'],
        "Image Height": image.height,
        "Image Width": image.width,
        "Image Format": image.format,
        "Image Mode": image.mode,
        "Frames in Image": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
    }

    for label, value in info_dict.items():
        #print(f"{label:25}: {value}")
        newfile.write(f"{label:25}: {value}"+'\n')
```

And the current output looks like this:

```
Filename                 : C:\Users\Eddie\Pictures\pics\X01CJ0035.JPG
Image DPI                : (72.0, 72.0)
Image Height             : 400
Image Width              : 600
Image Format             : JPEG
Image Mode               : RGB
Frames in Image          : 1
```

I would like to somehow print this data into a table and not have to have everything into a table and I am not sure how to do this.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Maybe Try this:
`dict = json.loads(info_dict) 
df = json_normalize(dict) 
print(df)`

Comment: where would I put that

Comment: Do you want to just print it horizontally?

Comment: @PyMan after you create the dict

Comment: I also get an error `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your second `for` loop to print it horizontally:

```
newfile.write("Filename   |  Image DPI    | ...\n")
for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
    # read the image data using PIL
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir, file))

    # extract other basic metadata
    info_dict = {
        "Filename": image.filename,
        "Image DPI": image.info['dpi'],
        "Image Height": image.height,
        "Image Width": image.width,
        "Image Format": image.format,
        "Image Mode": image.mode,
        "Frames in Image": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
    }

    line = ""
    for label, value in info_dict.items():
        line += f"|{str(value):<30} "  
    line += " |\n"  
    #print(line)
    newfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__` when I try this

Comment: weird, I am using your original loop. I'll check in a minute

Comment: Thank you I can show you my full code again or if you should show me everything you do, as in the full code.

Comment: @PyMan can you try again with the updated code? if it happens again, can you tell on which value it happens?

Comment: It works, Is there a way to put each one on a new line? i assume just add a `'\n'`

Comment: exactly, correct my answer :) please accept + upvote if it helped you :)

Comment: Is there a way to add a headder?

Comment: yes, I edit my snippet again

Comment: Do you know how to get the filename without the path?

Comment: That's a different question. might be enough to split by `/` but please ask it in a new question and I'll try to assist

Comment: I ahve posted a new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72996521/python-printing-file-name-shows-full-path-instead-of-just-the-file-name

Answer (score -2):

Try creating a pandas Dataframe from the dict you have. You can later add row per each dict. Don't forget to import pandas.

For reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html