# Python - Printing file name show's full path instead of just the file name

Tags: python

I have some code that prints the file name name however it prints out the whole file path instead of just the name

Here is what it prints now:

```
C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Pics\X00DL0027.jpg
```

Here is what I want

```
X00DL0027.jpg
```

Here is the script:

```
import json
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import os
import os.path
import PIL
from pandas import json_normalize

PIL.Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 384000000
rootdir = r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Pics"

newfile = newfile = open('meta.txt', 'w')
newfile.write("Filename                                     |  Image DPI                    | Image Height                  |   Image Width                 |   Image Format                |   Image Mode                  |   Image Frames                |\n")
for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
    # read the image data using PIL
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir, file))

# extract other basic metadata
info_dict = {
    "Filename": image.filename,
    "Image DPI": image.info['dpi'],
    "Image Height": image.height,
    "Image Width": image.width,
    "Image Format": image.format,
    "Image Mode": image.mode,
    "Frames in Image": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
}

line = ""
for label, value in info_dict.items():
    line += f"|{str(value):<30} "  
line += " |"  
newfile.write(line + '\n')
```

I am not sure what to change within the script.

Any help would be great

Comment: How would I implement this since `basename()`  takes one argument however I have two

Comment: `os.path.basename(image.filename)`.

Comment: You already construct the file as `os.path.join(rootdir, file)` so the name of the file `file`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:
`"Filename": os.path.basename(image.filename),`

Comment: But they already have that saved as `file`... No need to call another function...